# MRPT error: cannot find -lmrpt- base

Tags: gcc, cmake, codeblocks, cmake-gui

I am trying to run an example from the MRPT library but I am getting the error:

> cannot find -lmrpt- base

I am running ubunut 12.04 64-bit on a laptop. I am using Code::Blocks IDE with the GNU GCC compiler.

The CMakeLists.txt file had this code:

> SET(sampleName geometry3D) SET(PRJ_NAME "EXAMPLE_${sampleName}")
>
> PROJECT(${PRJ_NAME})
>
> CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.4) if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
>         cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)  endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)
>
> SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ".")
>
> FIND_PACKAGE(MRPT REQUIRED base)
>
> ADD_EXECUTABLE(${sampleName} test.cpp  )
>
> SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(    ${sampleName}   PROPERTIES      PROJECT_LABEL
>   "(EXAMPLE) ${sampleName}")
>
> SET(MY_DEFS ) IF(MY_DEFS) # If not empty
>     ADD_DEFINITIONS("-D${MY_DEFS}") ENDIF(MY_DEFS)
>
> TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${sampleName}   ${MRPT_LIBS}    ""      )
>
> IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
>     SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")
>   ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES
>   "Debug")
>
> IF("${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}" STREQUAL "MRPT") 
>     DeclareAppDependencies(${sampleName} mrpt-base) 
>   ENDIF("${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}" STREQUAL "MRPT")

the example can be found here http://www.mrpt.org/tutorials/programming/maths-and-geometry/2d_3d_geometry/ at the end of the page

how do I link the lmrpt to my project? what files am I looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO the problem was I did not install the drivers correctly :P. When I was installing I did the "cmake" and "make" command but dint do the "sudo make install" so the files dint go to the correct place. Silly me :P